# yowsup2 receives incomplete messages and strange characters

Tags: whatsapp, yowsup

I am try Yowsup2 with demo EchoClient:

```
yowsup-cli demos -c config.example -e
```

I receive messages, but they are incomplete and contain strange characters at the end of each text.

For example: I send "What is your name?" from my mobile phone to Yowsup2 number, and Yowsup2 receive (and print in the terminal):
Echoing hat is your name?������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a project using this library and i got stuck at this issue, i was waiting for someone to fix it and since no has i tried and got mine to work, this is what i did

clone the repository from github

**tested to work on python3.5**

in `yowsup/layers/axolotl/layer.py`

replace [line 192](https://github.com/s-alexey/yowsup/blob/padding/yowsup/layers/axolotl/layer.py#L192) which is

```
191                padded.extend(self.encodeInt7bit(len(plaintext)))
192                padded.extend(plaintext) # this is the line. replace it
193                padded.append(ord("\x01"))
```

with this

```
padded.extend(plaintext.encode() if isinstance(plaintext,str) else plaintext)
```

add @jlguardi fix in this [thread](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/issues/1356) but i had to modify it a bit to work for me

```
def decodeInt7bit(self, string):
    idx = 0
    while string[idx] >= 128:
        idx += 1
    consumedBytes = idx + 1
    value = 0
    while idx >= 0:
        value <<= 7
        value += string[idx] % 128
        idx -= 1
    return value, consumedBytes

def unpadV2Plaintext(self, v2plaintext):
    print(v2plaintext)
    v2plaintext=bytearray(v2plaintext,'utf8') if isinstance(v2plaintext,str) else v2plaintext
    end = (-(v2plaintext[-1])) # length of the left padding
    length,consumed = self.decodeInt7bit(v2plaintext[1:])
    return v2plaintext[1+consumed:end]
```

Looks clean on the client side

[image: 2016-05-11-11-27-07]

The garbled text though still appears on the server

[image: snapshot2]

not install `setup.py install`

*Hope it works for you*